# Does Keras support parametric optimizers?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, optimization, keras, deep-learning

When using keras can you add a term to an optimizers update rule, that the **optimizer** learns? So for instance on line 200 of keras's optimizer code on their github (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py) there is an update rule for SGD. Could you add a simple scalar variable to the SGD optimizer that would change the update formula to

new_p = (p + self.momentum * v - lr * g)*new_variable

where the new_variable is a scalar that is bounded within a certain range (say 0 to 1) and the SGD optimizer has to LEARN the appropriate value for new_variable?

How would a person go about making these kind of changes to an optimizer?

Answer (score 2):

That would sound weird, because for learning it's necessary to "get the gradients of the loss function" with respect to the weights. (This variable would be a weight, in the sense that it's a trainable var in Keras)

But notice that this var you proposed:

- does not participate in the loss function
- is used after the gradients (`g` in that formula) were calculated

So, independently from Keras, this kind of approach (learning the learning rate in a "backpropagation" learning framework) is sort of impossible.

Comment: I'm not under the impression that an optimization step has to be entirely related to some loss function. What about optimization under extreme uncertainty? You may not even know the "true" loss function and yet you can optimize for it.

Comment: I think you're talking about things waay beyond Keras.

Comment: @MattWard Keras and similar frameworks optimizers do [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) optimization, hence are limited to such things Daniel mentioned here.

Comment: @MattWard Keras and similar frameworks optimizers do [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) optimization, hence are limited to such things Daniel mentioned here.